# How do I check if UIAlertController has been dismissed before continuing to execute code?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I check if UIAlertController has been dismissed before continuing to execute code?

Here's one of my timers.

```
func Counting1(){
    timerCount+=1
    timerLabel.text="\(timerCount) secs"

    if timerRunning==true && timerCount >= timerMaximum {
        stop()
        intervalAlert()

        // Check if UIAlertController has been dismissed before continuing to start2()


        start2()
    }

}
```

And here's an example of one of my UIAlertControllers.

```
func configureWorkoutAlert(){
    let title = "Oh no!"
    let message = "You have to configure a workout before starting one!"
    let okText = "Okay."

    let alert=UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(okayButton)



    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I would like to wait until a UIAlertController has been dismissed until continuing to execute code...

Comment: Paste your code instead of code screenshots ;)

Comment: @QuentinHayot I tried to. It wouldn't paste correctly. It looked like a big jumbled mess. I figure that an admin will just correct it all for me because I'm new to all this.

Comment: @JamieMathieson No "admin" will come and do you work. If you want an answer you have to invest *your* time. Please read [ask]. Being new is not an excuse to break rules.

Comment: @idmean I pasted in my code yesterday and an admin fixed it. I did it the day before and an admin fixed it. They make my screenshots into actual images. They're really helpful. It's their job to be helpful. Please stop being so mean to admins or maybe they won't help you in the future... :3

Comment: @JamieMathieson Look, everyone can edit your post. I could also go and type in your code. But sorry, I don’t spend my time with copying code from people not able to use copy-paste. And to repeat what I said, there are no "admins", there are moderators and they do their work voluntarily – it’s not their job to clean or copy code!

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators.

Comment: @idmean After telling me that moderators wouldn't fix my code, you just fixed my code... Seems a little hypocritical, wouldn't you agree? Anyhow, thanks for helping :P

Comment: @JamieMathieson Well, I’m not an "admin", am I? And if *there is* code to fix, I always help. Now your question is completely fine.

Comment: In my last comment, I said 'moderator'. Not "admin"... Shhh:)

Comment: Maybe you should read this for future reference @JamieMathieson just like writing code if everyone else is doing it for you, you aren't going to learn anything. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: @sbarow I learn by making the same mistakes and learning the solutions to the same problems. This creates muscle memory in my brain and I learn to react appropriately to problems over time. It's how I evolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, you can use the completion of `UIAlertViewController` in your function to check it is dismiss and also to execute the code.

**Replace your below below method with mine:**

```
let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
```

**Instead of:**

When the user presses the okay button, the timer will be started!

```
let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

     //Start your second timer
     start2()
})
```

Remove the second timer `start2()` from `func Counting1`

Comment: This didn't work. I tried to use your method and what happened was the counter continued to count whilst the UIAlertViewController was shown. It was supposed to count AFTER it was dismissed.

Comment: @JamieMathieson Have you gone for the solution using "Boolean" value? it will definitely work!

Comment: I tried the boolean solution and it didn't work. Now, the counting just stops completely once the UIAlertViewController has been dismissed... :(

Comment: BTW, can you please specify what you are trying to achieve after dismissing Alert? @JamieMathieson

Comment: After dismissing the alert, I am trying to call a function which starts a timer. In fact, it's a function which calls three timer functions one after the other consecutively. And what I think is happening is `presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:` actually means once the UIAlertViewController has loaded not once it has been dismissed...

Comment: @JamieMathieson Sorry, my bad! I misunderstood. See the edited answer

Comment: Since making the update, an error has happened http://i.gyazo.com/904835aad0b0f17c4dde5e36b3364df8.png How do I fix this?

Comment: @JamieMathieson Please see the edited answer, you have put the word "handler:" two times

Comment: @JamieMathieson Thanks! Can you please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
    NSLog(@"Someone pressed OK");
}
```

I need to see the code to give a precise if clause.

Comment: Look at the screenshots. I tried to include the code using `code` tags but it didn't work correctly. I'll see if that buttonIndex thing works.

Comment: I included the code into the question, please re-load page and see.

Answer (score 0):

First define variable in the class :

```
var alert:UIAlertController!
```

Use it next without defining again , Just do as following to check if its dismissed or not :

```
if alert != nil {
// still presented 
}else {

// dismissed 
}
```

Comment: By the class, do you mean inside of `Counting1()` or inside of `configureWorkoutAlert()` ?

Comment: i meant after the class declaration. you define it as global and then use it or check will be quite easy !